# how to get property name and value in Tiled-software

Tags: libgdx, box2d, tiled

I am using libgdx, box2d and software called Tiled.

in software called Tiled I have create 2 objects on object layer. each objects I have given different property name, and value.

my question is that how can I get the property name and value using code?

i have tried:

```
if (mo.getProperties().get("direction").equals("left")) {
 float speed =  mo.getProperties().get("speed", Float.class);
}
```

getting a error: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: nm got it to working.

Answer (score -1):

Please refresh "access" directory.

As mentioned above, if you set the "direction" of the property in tiledmap. May be the reason "access" in the project file is not synchronized updates.